# Как получить исходник нерабочей вьюхи?

Tags: mysql

Одна вьюха (view) использовала в себе другую вьюху которая немного поменялась и теперь вторая вьюха не открывается и даже не хочет показать исходники чтобы ее тоже можно было поменять или хотя бы удалить и создать заново. Как быть? Я не помню тот код на память, а его было довольно много. Не хочется переписывать. Как добыть исходник нерабочей вьюхи?

Answer (score 0):

```
show create view view_name;
```

Покажет запрос на создание этого представления. В варнинге будет сообщение о том, что представление невалидно.

Альтернативно можно воспользоваться `mysqldump`. Тот ругнётся на невалидное представление, поэтому необходимо указать ключ `--force` - в этом случае в дампе будет дополнительный комментарий с текстом объявления view вроде такого:

```
-- failed on view `t_view`: CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `t_view` AS select `test`.`mytable`.`add_time` AS `add_time` from `mytable`
```